# Styled Component className minified in vite.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, rollupjs, vite

I'm trying to use Styled Components and have full classNames in development. It can be done with `babel-plugin-styled-components` and `displayName: true`, but my setting is not working.

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    reactRefresh(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: [
        ['babel-plugin-styled-components', { displayName: true }]
      ],
    }),
  ],
});
```

versions

```
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.9",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
"@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.13.2",
"styled-components": "^5.3.0"
"vite": "^2.4.4",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as follows;

1. First, install  `babel-plugin-styled-components`

```sh
npm i babel-plugin-styled-components
```

or

```sh
yarn add babel-plugin-styled-components
```

2. Edit `vite.config.js`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      babel: {
        plugins: [
          [
            'babel-plugin-styled-components',
            {
              displayName: true,
              fileName: false
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

You should see the full classname now.
[image]

Source: https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components/issues/350#issuecomment-979873241

Comment: Thanks, I actually did it with `vite-plugin-babel-macros` and `styled-components/macros` ..example is also in that thread. But this works as well 